# How to use Azurite for Integration test in Blobs

Tags: azure-blob-storage, integration-testing, azure-storage-emulator, azurite

Azurite does not connect with my local project for saving blobs inside local emulator.
I am trying to connect Azurite with my Integration test in blob storage? any guide

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you need a way to write integration test for blobs (Upload,Delete , get) you can use Azureit for that.
Azureit is inbuid in VS 2022, so can install Azurite and use it by mentioning your connection string as "ConnectionString": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true;"
up and run the Azureit. you can find application in
Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Azure Storage Emulator (run as admin)
[image]C:\Program Files\Microsoft